# Genymotion: Can i use my existing android system images from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, genymotion

My AVD is not working but after about four days of failed trial, I have downloaded Genymotion. But I have five android system images downloaded from Android SDK. How can i import them in genymotion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because Genymotion is based on Virtualization and AVD System Image is based on Emulation. and Genymotion using Virtualbox.

So, you should download a Genymotion available devices